# Why solar flux concentrators can achive only $\rm 1500°C$ of temperature if Sun temperature is $\rm 5500°C$?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, reflection, thermal-radiation, intensity

Why solar flux concentrators can achive only $\rm 1500°C$ of temperature if sun temperature is $\rm 5500°C$ ? If it is possible to concentrate a flux from a parabolic mirror of area $\rm 400\ m^2$ to a very small area we should get same temperature but with huge intensity so an absorbing material would heat up in matter of few seconds and if a transmittion through space is achived it could reach $\rm 400\ km$ until diffraction drop in intensity. But why not $\rm 5500°C$ instead of $\rm 1500°C$?

Comment: related (or even duplicate) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2679/226902

Answer (score 1):

I would not know of any material which can hold much more than 1500°C. What absorbing material do you think of?

Answer (score 0):

The sun is hold together and it is the way it is by the combined effects of gravity and internal --nuclear-- processes, not radiation coming from space and certainly not just electromagnetic processes. So, the forces containing this hot plasma are the inner sun processes --strong and electroweak interactions-- and gravity. On earth one would need a container that can absorb illimitable radiation and stable at that temperature (which is unachievable). Gravity would do nothing at this scale to hold things together, internal processes are not viable (except in nuclear reactors) and the electromagnetic interactions are not enough to do this.

On the other hand a container absorbs radiation but it also radiates (ideally as a black body) and it loses energy in that. A feasible reactor should be made of a material that absorbs, does not melt, can contain something and does not radiate too much. All of that sets a limit for a maximum temperature with just electromagnetic radiation reflected and concentrated in the reactor.